# Does anyone know of any RESTful API for FreeSWITCH?

Tags: api, rest, freeswitch

Does anyone know of any RESTful API for FreeSWITCH.  If none exists, what would you recommend as an alternative?

Thanks in advance!

.L.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the newish [Plivo](http://www.plivo.org/) for a RESTful API for FreeSWITCH.

From the site:

> Plivo is a framework which provides
>   web developers with basic building
>   blocks to create voice based apps in
>   the form of RESTXML (a small set of
>   specific XML elements that can control
>   a call) and RESTAPI (REST-based APIs).
>   So developers can completely do away
>   with learning the nitty-gritty of a
>   telephony engine.

Good luck!

Comment: keep in mind that Plivo is a pay-for-use service, and not an install alongside your FreeSWITCH server

Comment: You can use freeswitch module mod_verto here is link https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Restful